# SQLSRV Null value will be deleted by Aggregate or Set

Tags: php, sqlsrv

i trie to execute a Stored Procedure from PHP. My other SP´s are working correctly. But this one will make problems.

Here is my code for calling the SP:

```
            $sqlStmt = "EXEC MOBILE_CSKLIENT_LoadForSync @pCEGERAETNR = ?"; 
            $con = DatabaseManager::GetDatabaseConnection($serial); 
            $deviceNr = $this->GetDeviceNr($serial, $deviceId); 

            $res = sqlsrv_query($con, $sqlStmt, array($deviceNr)); 

            if($res == false) 
            { 
                    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); 
            } 
            else 
            { 
                    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true)); 
                    $result = array(); 
                    while($zeile = sqlsrv_fetch($res)) 
                    { 
                            echo sqlsrv_get_field($res, 0); 
                    } 
            }
```

here is my SP:

```
GO 
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[MOBILE_CSKLIENT_LoadForSync]    Script Date:     25.02.2014 08:36:01 ******/ 
 ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON 
GO 
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MOBILE_CSKLIENT_LoadForSync](@pCEGERAETNR FLOAT) 
AS 
BEGIN 
DECLARE @pLASTCHANGE datetime 
SET @pLASTCHANGE = (SELECT MAX(LASTCHANGE) FROM CEMITARB WHERE CEGERAETNR = @pCEGERAETNR) 

IF @pLASTCHANGE IS NULL 
BEGIN           
    SELECT K.KLIENTNR, K.PROGRAMMNR, K.NAME, 
            K.VORNAME, K.[STR], K.PLZ, K.ORT , K.TELEFON1, K.TELEFON2, K.GEBDAT, K.GESCHLECHT, K.KEYKLIFR1, K.MAINVERSION   
            FROM CSKLIENT K 
            INNER JOIN S1PAT P ON P.KLIENTNR = K.KLIENTNR 
            INNER JOIN CSKLIZR Z ON Z.KLIENTNR = K.KLIENTNR 
            WHERE P.AKTIV = 'J' 
            AND (Z.AUFNAHME IS NULL OR Z.AUFNAHME <= GetDate()) 
            AND (Z.ENTLASSUNG IS NULL OR Z.ENTLASSUNG >= GetDate()) 
     UNION 
     SELECT K.KLIENTNR, K.PROGRAMMNR, K.NAME, 
            K.VORNAME, K.[STR], K.PLZ, K.ORT , K.TELEFON1, K.TELEFON2, K.GEBDAT, K.GESCHLECHT, K.KEYKLIFR1, K.MAINVERSION 
            FROM CSKLIENT K 
            INNER JOIN H1BEW B ON B.KLIENTNR = K.KLIENTNR 
            WHERE B.AKTIV = 'J' AND ZIMMER IS NOT NULL AND BEREICH IS NOT NULL 
 END 
 ELSE 
 BEGIN 
      SELECT K.KLIENTNR, K.PROGRAMMNR, K.NAME, 
            K.VORNAME, K.[STR], K.PLZ, K.ORT , K.TELEFON1, K.TELEFON2, K.GEBDAT, K.GESCHLECHT, K.KEYKLIFR1, K.MAINVERSION   
            FROM CSKLIENT K 
            INNER JOIN S1PAT P ON P.KLIENTNR = K.KLIENTNR 
            INNER JOIN CSKLIZR Z ON Z.KLIENTNR = K.KLIENTNR 
            WHERE P.AKTIV = 'J' AND K.LASTCHANGE >= @pLASTCHANGE 
            AND (Z.AUFNAHME IS NULL OR Z.AUFNAHME <= GetDate()) 
            AND (Z.ENTLASSUNG IS NULL OR Z.ENTLASSUNG >= GetDate()) 
      UNION 
      SELECT K.KLIENTNR, K.PROGRAMMNR, K.NAME, 
            K.VORNAME, K.[STR], K.PLZ, K.ORT , K.TELEFON1, K.TELEFON2, K.GEBDAT, K.GESCHLECHT, K.KEYKLIFR1, K.MAINVERSION 
            FROM CSKLIENT K 
            INNER JOIN H1BEW B ON B.KLIENTNR = K.KLIENTNR 
            WHERE B.AKTIV = 'J' AND ZIMMER IS NOT NULL AND BEREICH IS NOT NULL 
            AND K.LASTCHANGE >= @pLASTCHANGE 
    END 
END
```

So i now get the Error:

```
Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Warnung: Ein NULL-Wert wird durch einen Aggregat- oder sonstigen SET-Vorgang gel\224scht.
```

Translatet to English:

```
A Null value will be delete by a aggregat or a set action
```

My Procedure works fine if i execute it from the SQL Management Studio.
The Procedure should return 222 rows.
I tried to set:

```
sqlsrv_configure("WarningsReturnAsErrors", 0);
```

But then nothing was returned from the Procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i found the solution:

the problem was this line in my SP:

```
SET @pLASTCHANGE = (SELECT MAX(LASTCHANGE) FROM CEMITARB WHERE CEGERAETNR = @pCEGERAETNR)
```

LastChange can be Null and this was the problem.
So i changed the code to:

```
IF((SELECT DISTICT LASTCHANGE FROM CEMITARB WHERE CEGERAETNR = @pCEGERAETNR) IS NULL)
BEGIN
     SET @pLASTCHANGE = NULL
END
ELSE
BEGIN
     SET @pLASTCHANGE = (SELECT MAX(LASTCHANGE) FROM CEMITARB WHERE CEGERAETNR = @pCEGERAETNR) 
END
```

Now my code executes fine. And sqlsrv_query returns the correct items.